# Accidentally deleted files from /boot

Tags: grub, debian-wheezy

I was trying to build a linux kernel for ARM, and, agh, I don't know what came over me and I executed "make install". It doesn't end there either: while attempting to delete the ramdisk and kernel image files generated, I accidentally deleted everything but the grub folder. Now the computer boots into a grub command line interface---i.e. I deleted the kernel X-(

Beside me is a computer running an identical kernel. Is there a way I can copy files between them, since I don't have the original installation disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the files from `/boot` onto a USB drive, boot the broken system from a rescue CD, then mount the USB drive and copy the files over.

As long as version and config are identical, this should work. Otherwise you will probably have to `chroot` into the broken system after booting the rescue CD, then reinstall from "inside" the system (reinstall packages to get back the files, and reinstall grub).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have a rescue CD either----how do I go about getting one?

Comment: @user3109672: Just dowload one :-). The installation CDs of most Linux distributions also work as rescue CDs - ideally use the CD you installed from (or re-download it). Failing that, use any modern Linux rescue CD, for example [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/).